# in structure how values get stored?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, structure

if a have a structure say

```
struct first
{
   int a;
   int b;
 };
```

now if i create its object

```
int main(){
struct first ob1,ob2;

ob1.a=5;
printf("%u  %u",&ob1,&(ob1.a));  //prints same address
printf("%d  %d",ob1,(ob1.a)); //  5,garbage value
return 0;}
```

my professor said that ob1 is a pointer to a structure. I want to know what address does ob1 and ob1.a also what value they store?

Also in c++ we have **this pointer** to assign value to ob1.a and ob2.a. In C how does compiler know in which object to store  value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ob1` is in no way a pointer.  It is a structure.

Since `a` is the first field of `struct first`, `&ob1` and `&ob1.a` are the same address (but have different types).

In C, the compiler knows which object to store to because you have to tell it. In your case, you said `ob1.a` or `ob2.a` respectively.

Editorial note:  use `%p` to print pointers, and don't try to pass a structure to `printf` at all.

Comment: why does ob1.a prints garbage value and ob1 prints 5?

Comment: @RaviBisla, because you  passed a structure to match with a `%d` format.  Doing so causes undefined behaviour.  As I mentioned in my editorial note, don't do that.

Comment: thanks. So according to your answer ob1 and ob1.a have been alloted the same address but &ob1 is of type structure first and &ob1.a is of type int. AM i correct carl?

Comment: No, `&ob1` is a `struct first *` and `&ob1.a` is `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

This line provokes undefined behavior because `printf` expect the first argument to be an `int` but you are passing in a `struct` that holds two ints:

```
printf("%d  %d",ob1,(ob1.a)); //  5,garbage value
```

The reason it prints `5` and a garbage value in your case is because of how your compiler passes parameters to functions: it puts a copy of `ob1` on the stack, followed by a copy of ob1.a. Since `a` is the first field, pushing `ob1` on the stack is equivalent to pushing first `ob1.a` and then `ob1.b` on the stack. The `printf` above is therefore equivalent to:

```
printf("%d  %d", ob1.a, ob1.b, ob1.a); //  5,garbage value
```

So, the first value printed is 5, which is the value that was given for `ob1.a`, followed by whatever garbage happens to be in `ob1.b`.

Needless to say, on another system, or with another compiler, you could see something completely different.

Comment: This answer is quite possibly correct, but it makes a lot of assumptions about system-specific behaviour.  For instance, if the structure were a bit larger, the Windows ABI would have passed a pointer to it.

Comment: True, for example on Linux amd64, compiling with GCC 4.7, the program outputs `5  5`. Undefined behavior :D